# Android: SQLite database helper runs onCreate every time I open my app

Tags: android, sqlite, activity-lifecycle

I'm using an extension of the SQLiteOpenHelper. My understanding is that onCreate only runs when the requested database does not exist. onOpen should run every time a database is opened.

This seems to work between activities within my app - I need to instantiate a new instance of the database helper in each activity, and onOpen is run but not onCreate.  However each time I restart the app, onCreate is being called.  Am I misunderstanding how this should work or did I simply implement it wrong?

Here's my helper class:

```
public class DBWrapper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyTest.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public DBWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("SQLite DBWrapper","OnCreate run");
        ver1(db);
        ver2(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d("SQLite DBWrapper","OnUpgrade run; oldVer: " + oldVersion + "; newVer: " + newVersion);
        if (oldVersion < 2) {ver2(db);}
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("SQLite DBWrapper","OnOpen run");
    }

    private void ver1(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("SQLite Wrapper","Creating new Version 1");
        db.execSQL("create table UserList (ID integer primary key, Name String, State String, Email String, Status String);");
        db.execSQL("create table Contacts (ContactID integer, Display_Name String, Email_Address String, IsPrimary integer);");
    }

    private void ver2 (SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("SQLite Wrapper","Updating to Version 2");
        db.execSQL("create table ActivityRecord (UserID String, ActID String, ActDate date, Rating REAL, Comment String, RateDate date, primary key(UserID,ActID));");
    }

//Other methods for inserting and retrieving data
}
```

This is how I create an instance of the helper in each activity:

```
private DBWrapper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    DBHelper = new DBWrapper(this);
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

My logcat is indicating every time I restart my app (in debug mode at least) the onCreate is being called (along with ver1 and ver2).  What have I done wrong?

UPDATE: I added more logging and found that A) This is happening on both release and debug variants; B) when I logged db.getVersion() in onCreate, it reported "0". So that either means it forgot the version number when I closed and reopened the app or the db was deleted when the app closed.

Comment: do you have your emulator/device on keep activities after exit or something like taht?

Comment: Running on my device.  I'm not familiar with what you're asking about

Comment: Please, post your ContentProvider class.

Comment: I'm not using a ContentProvider.

Comment: It shouldn't create your database again each time you launch the app. You should only get the `onCreate` callback when you try to open a database that doesn't exist yet and Android creates a new one. You aren't calling `Context.deleteDatabase(...)` anywhere in your project, are you?

Comment: @Karakuri I'm not calling deleteDatabase anywhere.  I am completely confused. The only thing I think might be happening is that the DB is being deleted when activity is destroyed, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Are you running in an emulator or on a real device?

Comment: Running on 3 different real devices, both as a signed release apk and as a connection to Android Studio in debug mode

Comment: @Scott, you didn't create the tables. Check my answer and use "TEXT" instead of "STRING".

Answer (score -2):

Dont create instance of DBWrapper everytime you launch an activity.Just create it once when your application instance is created and use the same instance across all activities of app.See if you still notice the problem.

I doubt multiple instances of DBWrapper are being created in your application(Although multiple instances should have worked logically).

Refer code below:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

DBWrapper mDbwrapper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDbwrapper=new DBWrapper();//Share this object with all the activities of the class
    }


}
```

Add this line to manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyApplication">
```

Comment: The problem is that onCreate is run when the application starts.  It's working correctly and not calling onCreate when launching other activities.